# How do you configure AWS API Gateway HTTP GET to return the BASE64 string as binary data?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, binary-data

I am trying to send binary data from my AWS Lambda function as a response to an AWS Gateway GET Method that **DOES NOT** use Lambda Proxy integration.  I have tried all sorts of variations but still can't make it work, although I feel like I am close.

My API Gateway HTTP request is returning:
[image]

But what I want is is the actual binary data:
[image]

I did attempt using a mapping template, but was unsuccessful due to my lack of understanding the templating syntax/behavior(I tried `$util.base64Decode($input.body)` but that produced a server error).

But I wasn't sure if that was even necessary since I have the content handling set to `Convert to binary.`

[image]

Comment: Use Lambda Proxy Integration. It's much easier because mapping templates are limited.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem but I used a proxy url. Make sure to enable Binary Media Types. Also do not forget to deploy your changes, simply saving is not enough. Also make sure you have the correct content type in the header with client sending the payload.

[image]